# Cannot deploy doctrine discriminator update

Tags: php, symfony, proxy, doctrine

I have a php application using symfony2 and doctrine.  I need to add a class to a discriminator map for different content types.  Currently I have the following base abstract class for the discriminator map:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PrintSyndicate\HubBundle\EntityRepository\ContentRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 *  * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({   "site_content"="SiteContent",
                            "site_content_image"="SiteContentImage",
                            "site_content_carousel"="SiteContentCarousel",
                            "site_content_html"="SiteContentHtml",
                            "site_content_static_text"="SiteContentStaticText",
                            "apparel_front"="ApparelFrontContent",
                            "apparel_back"="ApparelBackContent",
                            "blanket"="BlanketContent",
                            "canvas"="CanvasContent",
                            "phone_case"="PhoneCaseContent",
                            "tablet_case"="TabletCaseContent",
                            "pillow"="PillowContent",
                            "tote"="ToteContent",
                            "poster"="PosterContent",
                            "sticker"="StickerContent",
                            "mug"="MugContent",
                            "gift_card"="GiftCardContent",
                            "collection_image"="CollectionImageContent",
                            "greeting_card"="GreetingCardContent",
                            "towel"="TowelContent"
                        })
 * @ORM\Table(name="content", indexes={@Index(name="content_guid_index", columns={"guid"})})
 **/
abstract class Content extends Model 
{
```

The new class I want to add is the TowelContent class, that looks like this:

```
<?php

// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/TowelContent.php
namespace PrintSyndicate\HubBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinTable as JoinTable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn as JoinColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use PrintSyndicate\HubBundle\Entity\Content;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TowelContent extends Content
{
    /**
     * Validate that this is a well formated apparel front image
     */
    public function validate($errors = array())
    {
        //do initial validation
        $parentValid = parent::validate($errors);
        //check if png
        //check sizing
        //
        return $parentValid;
    }
}
```

For whatever reason when I try to run php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod after deleting all files in the app/cache folder I get the following error

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Entity 'PrintSyndicate\HubBundle\Entity\TowelContent' has to be part of the discriminator map of 'PrintSyndicate\HubBundle\Entity\Content' to be properly mapped in the inheritance hierarchy. Alternatively you can make 'PrintSyndicate\HubBundle\Entity\TowelContent' an abstract class to avoid this exception from occurring.
```

What I don't understand is that it clearly is part of the discriminator map and the cache folder has been deleted so I don't know how it's seeing it as not part of the discriminator map...

Also, if I try to deploy without clearing the cache I get the following error on every route:

```
Warning: require(/app/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PrintSyndicateHubBundleEntityStatus.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/app/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PrintSyndicateHubBundleEntityStatus.php' (include_path='/app/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /app/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/app/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PrintSyndicateHubBundleEntityStatus.php' (include_path='/app/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')' in /app/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:209 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /app/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209
```

Any help would be amazing, I've been beating my head against the wall on this all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out in my case for anyone who is googling the same issue.  Somehow in our config_prod.yml file the following lines were commented out:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

Uncommenting these lines solved the issue.